# Automated processing using windows services/applications

Tags: .net

In our company, we have a lot of services running on our main server. While I was studying each service, I noticed that most of it are the same application with different parameters. We have 600+ services but to sum it up, it should be 9 applications only. Basically the same services were installed per client supplied with different parameters in the config file.

I am planning of trimming down the main services and just spool a separate process using console application for each client for every schedule or process demand.

I have tried this using a simple service and a console application for POC and it is working fine. I am just worried if the approach that I am thinking would have a problem in the long run. Based on my POC, it shouldn't have any major issues aside from the timing which I am still working.

I don't know if this is off topic but I am asking for your advise masters. My idea is that, I wanted to avoid installing another instance for the same service for each client. This is a burden when your server encounters a problem and you will need to set up your services on another server. Do you see a major drawback about the approach?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: _"600+ services"_ - golly your computer must take an eon to boot up!

Comment: Reading this again, what is the average concurrent services running?

Comment: @MickyD - I am not sure, i haven't looked at it yet actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the service is performing the same but the parameters are different, it is always preferred to keep it as a single service. With this approach, it would be easy for the **maintenance**.

Pl. drop a message for further queries.

Comment: However it is always safe to run both live server & your current approach (POC) together for less headache of rolling back the changes for any unanticipated problems.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about the maintainability when I came up with this idea. I hope my boss would consider the approach. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is just configurations, you can have the same instance running and then spawn off a process per configuration item. This would allow you to have a centralized means of controlling the creation of tasks.

Configuration can be stored in a database structure, and maybe even have some sort of small UI application which allows users to modify the configurations. You could also push things a little bit further and maybe have some sort of authentication system so that you can control which users get to modify which configurations.

Obviously since you will have one centralized process which spawns off other processes, make sure that you log the appropriate information in your logging, so that you can better keep track of things.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful idea, I think having UI that modify etc. for the config of each process per client would be nice. :)

Answer (score -1):

It is not an advise master. But for this kind of things (client-server), have you take a look to WCF (Windows Communication Service).

There could be some exception in some case but most of time you should have only one service on your server side. It's hard to say without any informations on your business requirement.

Comment: OP is not talking about _that_ sort of _service_

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, although as @MickyD mention, my question is about Win Services. :-)

Comment: And what are doing theses Windows Services ? Do they listen and process query from client (software) ? Do they process automated task for clients (as a business entity?). Creating 600 console app (which are UI app) on a server instead of 600 Windows services look like the very same for me. That's why I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do at a higher level...

Comment: Most of the services are processing automated reports, parsing hand-off files generated from another application.

Comment: Your requirement looks more like task than service. Take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//428303 and ask yourself if your are really in a right approach with service. Notice that I haven't all card in my hand. I really cann't say what is the best for you.